# REST collections of collections, promoting and demoting

Tags: rest, api

We have a resource called tasks. With the following endpoints, we can list all tasks, and create tasks:

```
GET:  /tasks
POST: /tasks
```

The problem is that tasks can contain sub-tasks, and we wish to embed the functionality to both support promoting sub-tasks to their own tasks and demoting tasks to sub-tasks of another task.

The naïve approach should be to delete the sub-task and create it again as a task and vice-versa, but we find this a tad too naive.

The second option we have come up with is to support endpoints such as the following, where `{id}` is the ID of the task, and `{sid}` is the ID of the sub-task:

```
POST: /tasks/{id}/add/{sid}
POST: /tasks/{id}/upgrade/{sid}
```

The first endpoint should *add* a task to another task, thereby deleting the first task and adding a copy as a sub-task to the second task. The second endpoint should *upgrade* a sub-task to a task from another task, thereby deleting the sub-task and adding a copy as a task.

So our question is if this would be considered good practice, or if there are some other options which we have not considered?

Comment: Verbs in a URI is not RESTful

Comment: Would there exist a suitable replacement for these verbs which would convey the same intent?

Comment: yep, a question though - how do you reference a sub task? And how does a sub task reference its parent task?

Comment: Please note that a RESTful API may not be the correct approach for a *task-based* system. A task-based system is by nature process-oriented, and processes are notoriously difficult (if at all possible while remaining user-friendly) to correctly map to a RESTful API. The creation of the task can still be something like @cassiomoli's answer, but something like a promotion would *definitely* be clearer and easier to use with just `POST /tasks/{id}/promote`.

Comment: @user991710 I'd disagree about it being "easier", it's certainly clearer...much like anything else when you use more verbose language. However, if I seen a `PATCH` call against a resource that changed a value, that would be just as clear IMO.

Comment: IMO, easier and clearer in this context are very much the same: if the API endpoints are clearer and cannot be misconstrued for something other than what they do, the user will have an easier time making use of it. Besides, how would you `PATCH` an e.g.`user` resource to initiate a password reset? An action is not always a simple change in the state of the resource - it potentially triggers an entire process chain. IMO, the more complex the process, the simpler the entrypoint should be to avoid any possible errors.

Comment: @user991710 I personally feel you are mixing ease of use of API _consumption_ vs implementation - and any benefit you feel is gained by using a CRUD URI, IMO, is just superficial i.e. "it looks nice". It's irrelevant to the user how complex a process is behind the scenes, ultimately the user will still consume _some_ endpoint to do it, and whether that's a `POST /tasks/{id}/promote` or `PATCH /tasks/{id}` is almost irrelevant, apart from the fact that if you _want_ to be RESTful then the latter is preferred. A well documented, validated and informative API would be very easy to consume.

Comment: In fact, I was speaking *solely* from a consumption point-of-view. I agree with the latter part ("whether that's a... is irelevant [...]"). IMHO, however, if your API consumers *need* to check the documentation to find out what the endpoint even *does*, then the net result is making the entry barrier higher for your users - not to mention that documentation may not always be 100% up-to-date (but that's not really the crux of my argument here). Higher entry barrier == more annoyed API users. :)

Comment: @user991710 but you used a server concern i.e. _"how would you `PATCH` an e.g. `user` resource"_ (which I presume you were alluding to implementation) as an argument for why a URI would be "easier" to use ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Consumers would _always_ need to check documentation, are you telling me whenever you use a new API you don't read the docs to familiarise yourself with the supported endpoints, expected status codes, payload formats etc.? You've more or less contradicted your own point, an undocumented API would be immediately more difficult to consume than one that is documented.

Comment: @James, initially, tasks were to have an array of subtasks accessible from `GET /tasks`. But I find @cassiomolin's linked-list-like idea much more appealing.

Comment: @James Yes and no. As an API consumer I would have a much easier time remembering a descriptive endpoint rather than the corresponding HTTP verb for that action that I want to do - even more so if the API has breaking changes where the verb meanings evolve to mean different things between major versions - *not* a standard practice mind you, but the structure of the endpoint allows it, and it would not be immediately obvious to a consumer if it is a bug in the API or in the consumer code. I agree with the documentation of course. I guess it boils down to preference in the end. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to highlight that [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) doesn't care about the URI spelling at all. However, once the central piece of the REST architectural style is the *[resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)*, it makes sense that the URIs uses *nouns* instead of *verbs*.

The REST architectural style is protocol independent, but it's commonly implemented on the top of the HTTP protocol. In this approach, the HTTP method is meant to express the *operation* that will be performed over the resource identified by a given URI.

---

Your question doesn't state what your domain looks like. But let's consider you have something like:

```js
+-------------------+
|       Task        |
+-------------------+
|- id: Long         |
|- title: String    |
|- parent: Task     |
|- children: Task[] |
+-------------------+
```

---

Creating a task could be expressed with a [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) request:

```js
POST /tasks
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "title": "Prepare dinner"
}
```

```js
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /tasks/1
```

Creating a subtask could expressed with a [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) request indicating the `parentId` in the payload:

```js
POST /tasks
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "parentId": 1
  "title": "Order a pizza"
}
```

```js
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /tasks/2
```

Promoting a subtask to a task could be achieved by setting the `parentId` to `null` using a [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) request:

```js
PATCH /tasks/2
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  { 
    "op": "replace", "path": "/parentId", "value": null
  }
]
```

```js
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

Updating a task to become a subtask could be achieved by setting the `parentId` using a [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) request:

```js
PATCH /tasks/2
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  { 
    "op": "replace", "path": "/parentId", "value": 1 
  }
]
```

```js
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

The above examples use [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (`application/json-patch+json`) as payload for the [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789). Alternatively, you could consider [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) (`application/merge-patch+json`). I won't go through the differences of such formats once it will make this answer overly long. But you can click the links above and check them by yourself.

For handling errors, refer to the [error handling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2) section of the [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), the document that defines the [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method.

---

I also appreciate that some APIs avoid using [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) for a number of reasons that are out of the scope of this answer. If that's the case, you *could* consider [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) instead. In this approach, the state of the resource will be *replaced* with the state defined in the representation sent in the request payload.

Alternatively you could have an endpoint such as `/tasks/{id}/parent`, supporting [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4). In this approach, the client just have to send a representation of the parent (such as an id) instead of a full representation of the task.

Pick the approach that suits you best.

Comment: I was waiting on clarification from the OP re how subtasks are linked, but this is effectively the route I would've suggested going down because in either scenario all that would change is the tasks reference to its parent task. I'd even argue that you may not necessarily need to suggest the operation / remove tasks from a parent, if tasks themselves hold a ref to their parent then `{ "parentId": "xxxx" }` to switch to another or `{ "parentId": null }` to orphan a task.

Comment: @cassiomolin thank you for your answer, and sorry for the lack of specificity of how the tasks relate to the sub-tasks. I find your answer answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

REST is an abbrevation for the transfer of a resource' current state in a representation format supported by the client. As REST is a generalization of the World Wide Web, the same concepts you use for the Web also apply to applications following the REST architecture model. So the basic question resolves around: *How would you design your system to work on Web pages* and apply the same steps to your design.

As Cassio already mentioned that the spelling of URIs is not of importance to clients, as a URI remains a URI and you can't deduce from a URI whether the system is "RESTful" or not. Actually, there is no such thing as "RESTful" or "RESTless" URIs as a URI, as stated above, remains a URI. It is probably better to think of a URI as a key used for caching responses in a local or intermediary cache. Fielding made [support of caching even a constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Cacheability) and not just an option.

As REST is not a protocol but just an architectural style, you are basically not obligated to implement it stringent, though you will certainly miss out on the promised benefits, such as the decoupling of clients from APIs, the freedom to evolve the server side without breaking clients and making clients in general more robust against changes. Fielding even stated that [applications that violate the constraints he put on REST shouldn't be termed REST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) at all, to avoid confusions.

I don't agree with user991710 in one of his comments that REST can't be used to represent processes, I agree however that REST shouldn't attempt to create new verbs either. As mentioned before, REST is about transfering a resources current state in a supported representation format. If a task can be represented as a stream of data then it can be presented to a client as well. The self descriptiveness of messages, i.e. by using a media type that defines the rules on how to process the data payload, guarantees that a client will be able to make sense of the data. I.e. your browser is able to render images, play videos, show text and similar stuff as it knows how to interpret the data stream accordingly. Support for such fields can be added via special addons or plugins, that may be loaded dynamically during runtime without even having to restart the application.

If I had to design tasks for Web pages, I'd initially return a pagable view of existing tasks, probably rendered in a table, with a link to a page that is able to create new tasks or a link in each row to update or delete an existing task. The create-new and update pages may use the same HTML form to enter or update a tasks information. If a task should be assigned as sub-task to an other task, you may be able to either select a parent task from a given set of tasks, i.e. in a drop-down text field, or enter the URI of the parent in a dedicated field. On submitting the task, HTTP method `POST` would be used that will perform the operation based on the servers own semantic, so wheter a new resource is created or one or multiple ones are updated is up to the server. The quintesence here is, that everything a client may be able to do, is taught by the server. The form to add new or update existing tasks just informs the client which fields are supported (or expected) by the server. There is actually no external, out-of-band knowledge needed by a client in order to perform a request. A server has still the option to reject incomplete payloads or payloads that violate certain constraints and a client will know by receiving an appropriate error message.

As clients shouldn't parse or interpret URIs, they will use certain text describing what the URIs do. In a browser a picture of a dustbin may be used as symbol for deletion, while a pencil may be used as symbol for updating an existing entry (or the like). As humans we quickly realize what these links are intended for whithout having to read the characters of the actual URI.

The last two paragraphs just summed up how the interaction model on a common Web page may look like. The same concepts should be used in a REST architecture as well. The content you exchange may vary more, ideally with [standardized representation formats](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), compared to the big brother, the Web, though still the concepts of links are used to reference from one resource to other resources and server teaches clients what it needs apply here. Compared to HTML, however, you can utilize more HTTP methods than just `POST` and `GET`. A deletion of a resource's representation would probably make more sense with a `DELETE` method than with a `POST` method. Also, for updates either `PUT` or `PATCH` may make more sense, depending on the situation. In contrast of using sensible pictures for hinting users on what this link might be good for, link-relation names should be used that hint clients about the purpose of the link. Such link-relation names should be [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), or at least express common sense such as expressed though special [ontologies](http://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/), or use [absolute URIs as extension mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2).

You may add dedicated links to show a collection of all tasks based on certain filters, i.e. all tasks or only parent tasks and what not, so a client can iterate through the task it is interested in. On selecting a task you may add links to all sub-tasks a client can invoke to learn what these subtasks are, if interested. Here the URIs of the tasks may remain unchanged, which supports caching by default. Note that I didn't mention anything in regards to how you should store the data in your backend as this is just some implementation details a client is usually not interested in. This is just a perfect case where a domain model does not necessarily have to be similar to a resources state representation.

In regards to which HTTP operation to perform a task promotion or demotion is basically some design choice that also may depend on the representation format the payload is exchanged for. As HTTP only supports `POST` and `GET`, such a change could be requested via `POST`, other media types might support other [HTTP methods](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), such as `PUT`, which, according to its [specification (last paragraph page 27)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), is allowed to have side-effects, or `PATCH`, which needs to be applied atomically - either fully or not at all. `PATCH` actually is similar to patching software, where a set of instructions should be applied on some target code. William Durand summarized this concept in a quite cited [blog-post](https://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/). However, he later on updated his blog post to mention that via `application/merge-patch+json` a more natural and intuitive way of "updating" resources could be used. In regards to form support, there exist a couple of drafts such as [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halo-json (halform)](http://halform.herokuapp.com/), [Ion](https://ionspec.org/) or [hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/) that offer such definition but lack currently wider library support or a final standard. So a bit of work needs yet to put into an accepted standard.

To wrap this post up, you should design your API like you'd design your system to work for Web pages, apply the same concepts you use for interaction on typical Web pages, such as links and forms, and used them in your responses. Which HTTP operation you perform the actual promotion or demotion with, may be dependent on the actual media type and what HTTP operations it supports. `POST` should work in all cases, `PUT` is probably more intuitive to typical updates done in Web forms while patching would require your client to actually calculate the steps needed to transform the current resource' representation to the desired one (if you use `application/json-patch+json` in particular). `application/merge-patch+json` may  be applicable as well, which would simplify the patching notably, as the current data contained in the form could just be sent to the server and default rules would decide whether a field got removed, added or updated.

Comment: That's a very well-written answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

you can divide your route with :

```
POST : /tasks => for create or add tasks 

PUT/PATCH : /tasks => for upgrading your tasks
```

or even be more specific about it you can pass :id to params. I think the best approach is whenever you need to **change delete update or get** a specific object you must use :id in your params

```
PUT/PATCH/GET : /tasks/:id
```

Comment: I find this a bit unclear. Just how would upgrading a sub-task look? Keep in mind that tasks lie within other tasks